# How many people are writing novels?

Tags: jobs

A YouGov survey shows that [60%](https://yougov.co.uk/news/2015/02/15/bookish-britain-academic-jobs-are-most-desired/) of British men an women would like to become an author. [81%](http://www.nytimes.com/2002/09/28/opinion/think-you-have-a-book-in-you-think-again.html) of Americans feel they have a book in them.

**But how many people do actually set out to write a novel?**

---

*Replies to comments*

@Jay In the context of my question, "set out to write" means that they begin to write it. The number I'm after includes those that eventually give up, as well as those that manage to publish their novel.

@MarkBaker: I'm not after professionals here. I'm trying to understand the situation of aspiring writers.

The percentage of the population that attempts to write a novel directly reflects how desirable writing as a profession appears to the general public, compared to other professions.

@ggiaquin Any numbers would be helpful at all. Of course there are cultural differences, but given the scarcity of data, numbers from all over the world are relevant for a first impression.

If the scope of this question must be regionally limited, I am mostly interested in the Western world. There is a lot of cross publishing among countries of Europe and the Americas, there are many cultural similarities, and there should be some similarity among aspiring writers, too. Also, those are the countries where most of our users come from, so that is where we will have most information.

Comment: If we start with the [2013 Publish Book Counts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Books_published_per_country_per_year) and then figure that the vast majority of first time authors give up before publishing their first work, the result is pretty sobering.  I think it is fair to claim that 99% of first time authors fail to finish, so the 2.2 million who succeeded in 2013 suggest a total writing population of about 200 million or about 3% of our 7 billion planetary population.  If you limit that just the literate, it still doesn't exceed 4% and that is with an arguably high % failure rate.

Comment: BTW...  I put this in comments because I couldn't find a decent source for the author failure rate, so the entire post above is just my opinion.

Comment: I think there is a huge problem of definition here. Counting every notebook stuffed with earnest scrawl as a book start is a bit like counting every four year old drawing windows on a cardboard box as a housing start. Novelist is a profession and a level of awareness of and engagement with that profession and its standards and practices should be required to seriously say that someone is "working on a novel".

Comment: @MarkBaker, agreed.  ...and categories like "would like to become an author" or "have a book in them" don't even require a notebook.  Those surveys are measuring aspirations and dreams.

Comment: I like Stephen King's distinction, on a live talk show he was asked what he tells people that want to write. He said, "Then write." Then basically that most people that say it ***do not*** want to write, but ***to have written.*** They want to be famous, or rich, or making the rounds of TV talk shows for their book tour. But a person that truly wants to write can do it for nearly nothing, and if they read and work they will eventually get good at it and start selling. While if they only want ***to have written*** they will likely never put in the many years it takes to get good enough to sell.

Comment: Sry, this is no place for surveys.

Comment: @ggiaquin It is not a survey or poll question. It is asking for a piece of data -- a number.  There are issues with defining the parameters of that data, and one could question its relevance, but there may be measures and some users may be aware of them and be able to respond.

Comment: @MarkBaker good point. Still though, as it stands now, it's fairly broad. How  many people actually set out to write a novel in what basis? Americans? The World? Does genre matter? Does an 8 year old who writes a picture book for fun count? There are so many metrics that even still, I feel this question should be re-evaluated for a more specific answer.

Comment: There's a big difference between, "I'd like to write a book some day" and actually putting words on paper. And there's a big difference between starting a book and finishing a book. And there's a big difference between finishing a book and publishing a book. If you asked, "Would you like to be president (or prime minister or whatever)?", I'm sure a lot of people would say yes who have never done a thing to get involved in politics. Similarly if you asked, "would you like to travel around the world?", "would you like to be an olympic athlete?", or dozens of other such questions.

Comment: @Jay See my edit.

Comment: "aspiring" is not a useful category here. I have aspired to all sorts of things, and have the disused equipment (art supplies, instruments, etc) in my closets to prove it. I'm pretty sure every little boy and healthy number of little girls at one point aspired to be a fireman. I suspect that everyone who reads aspires to be a writer for at least ten minutes. You need a measurable standard of commitment to make this meaningful.

Comment: @MarkBaker The measurable standard of commitment is given in my question as "set out to write a novel", which I later define as "begin to write it".

Comment: That is not a measurable standard. The question as it stands is not really answerable.

Comment: @MarkBaker How is that not measurable? You can ask people whether or not they have ("ever" = lifetime prevalence or "within the last year" = one year prevalence) begun to write a novel. If you draw a representative sample you can use statistical tests to infer the number within the population. Scientists do something like this all the time, in fact it is my daily job. Please explain how you think that what I'm paid to do every day is not possible?

Comment: There is a world of difference between how many people *say* they are writing a novel and how many people are *writing* a novel. In any case, it is clear that if there is any such statistic exists, no one here knows about it. And in any case, it is irrelevant to the craft of professional writing per se.

Comment: "Begin to write" is certainly more specific, but if taken literally still includes a lot of inconsequential efforts. If someone wants to write a novel, and one day he sits at his computer and types, "Bob entered the room", and then his wife walks in the room and he puts it aside and never comes back to it ... he's "started to write", but, etc. Or what if he jots down some notes and never gets any further? Etc.

Answer (score 1):

I know you are looking for data, but based on your edit I will say, don't worry about the numbers, or how many are trying out for the job. Does it change the way you interview if you know you are the only one vs 1 of 100? Hopefully not if you want to get hired because nothing says it has to be you guaranteed or from the 100. They could still choose to wait.

You know that most people fail for various of reasons. Some get derailed by life, others lose interest in their own story, but again that really has no relevance to you making the best story you can! Whether you are book #1 of 2000 submissions or of 10, either way, there is still a vetting process to go through. Many people choose to self-publish because they don't want to wait (it could take months/years) or they get declined and still want to publish anyways.

The state of writing as a profession is no doubt a rough path. Many people set to write full time and earn enough to actually be able to write full time but not many actually achieve that. It's very competitive and again why many choose to self-publish as it provides the best path to getting published.

In the end, good books will rise up from the bad. I can't think of any book that has been a huge hit and also self-published, but this may also be because a publisher approached them and they took over the book.

Sorry I don't have any specific numbers, but I wanted to address a few things you brought up in your edit. Bottom line is to just write! Write your best you can! Once you have a book actually finished and edited, then worry about competition. Until then, you can't compete if you have no product ;).

Comment: I really just want that number.

Comment: @WalterFenn I don't think you will actually get a number. Lots of people will admit to wanting to write as you quoted 81% feel they have a story to share. Of them, you are looking at probably at most 50-60% will begin to write. However, not many people will admit to actually starting the writing process. That is usually followed by the "let me read it!" as many writers here are even too nervous to share their own work. So you will never get an honest answer as even some may lie and say they are when they actually are not.

Comment: I know from my circle of friends, several have stated they wanted to, of them, only a couple actually started but none of them have actually finished. I also know some others who claim they write for a living, though they have never been published and mostly write roleplay. Not sure why you really really need that number unless it's some sort of essay/report but there are too many variables to discern truth from lies and it would be a statistic that should be taken lightly.

Comment: You know that 81% of Americans want to write or feel they can write a book, so you know that it can't be anything greater than that who actually do. Logic states that you won't have 100% of that 81% actually start to write and would be closer to half +- some deviation. I have tried to look around for you but found no statistics outside what you quoted in OP so you will need to probably form your own survey or use other data to derive a conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused, maybe because I skimmed over the question. Are you looking for a poll, like a raise of hands from members of SE writing a novel currently?

Asking in a writers forum, may give you a limited sample size, but still might be interesting if it falls within the rules. I'm still new here so I may be a poor one to answer.

Anyways that said, I've been working on a story for most of my life, but like most of my hobbies I work in spurts. I will focus one at a time until I grow bored, then put it aside and work on another hobby to develop it until the challenge wears off, I get bored, and I cycle back to a hobby and the skills I long to develop.
Writing is one of the hobbies I'm most passionate with, but is also the weakest of my skills, in my self reflective opinion. Some day I hope to complete a novel and have it published, but I have a long way to go and my tendency to switch off to other hobbies can get in the way.